# How to integrate a --worker-class of gunicorn in supervisor config setting?

Tags: python, flask, ubuntu-14.04, gunicorn, supervisord

I have configured a supervisor on the server like this:

```
[program:myproject]
command = /home/mydir/myproj/venv/bin/python /home/mydir/myproj/venv/bin/gunicorn manage:app -b <ip_address>:8000
directory = /home/mydir
```

I have installed gevent on my virtual environment but I don't know how can I implement it on the supervisor `command` variable, I can run it manually through terminal like this:

```
gunicorn manage:app -b <ip_address>:8000 --worker-class gevent
```

I tried to include a path when I call gevent in supervisor command just like python and gunicorn, but it's not working, honestly, I don't know what's the correct directory/file to execute gevent and I am also not sure if this is the correct way to execute a worker class in supervisor. I am running on Ubuntu v14.04

Anyone?Thanks

Comment: read the normal log and error log which `supervisord` generates when running this program. If still you can't get a clue, paste the log here.

Comment: You shouldn't need to include the full path to anything except gunicorn. You shouldn't need the reference to Python at all. gunicorn should use the interpreter it was installed against.

Answer (score 1):

Already made a solution for this. But I am not 100% sure if it is correct, after searching a hundred times, I finally came up with a working solution :)

Got this from [here](https://honza.ca/2011/05/deploying-django-with-nginx-and-gunicorn), I've created a gunicorn.conf.py file on my project directory containing:

```
worker_class = 'gevent'
```

And integrated this file on supervisor config setting:

```
[program:myproject]
command = /home/mydir/myproj/venv/bin/python /home/mydir/myproj/venv/bin/gunicorn -c /home/mydir/myproj/gunicorn.conf.py manage:app -b <ip_address>:8000
directory = /home/mydir
```

And start running the supervisor:

```
sudo supervisorctl start <my_project>
```

And poof! It's already working!